# copiar tabela 1 pra tabela 2

Tags: php

copiar tabela 1 pra tabela 2

```
include_once "conexao.php";

session_start();

$result= "INSERT INTO tb_tabela2 (cl_coluna, created) SELECT cl_coluna ,created FROM tb_tabela ";
```

me ajunte o que eu to fazendo errado ?

Comment: Não se pode fazer dois comandos assim, recomendo por isso em uma function

Comment: obg vo ver se acho algo na net , pois so novato nisso kkk.

Comment: Qual erro está acusando?

Comment: entao quando coloco direto no phpmyadmin , ela faz tudo certo transfere os dados de uma pra outra normal , quando coloco em um aquivo php pra quando eu chamar ele e executa a tarefa nao faz nada e nao da erro algum

Comment: no banco tem duas tabelas cada tabela com uma coluna , quero copiar de uma pra outra quando eu enviar do meu form , so isso mais ta dificio pq so bem cabeça dura kk.

Comment: Você está declarando um comando SQL no seu PHP, mas não está executando. Como executar depende de como é feita a sua conexão. Mostre o conteúdo do conexao.php (mas remova dados sensíveis como servidores externos e senhas!).

Comment: <?php 
include_once"conexao.php";
session_start();

$result = "INSERT INTO tb_tabela2 ( cl_coluna , created ) SELECT cl_coluna ,created FROM tb_tabela";
 
 if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
 $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:green;'> cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
 header("Location: cadastrar.php.");
 }else{
 $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'> não foi cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
 //header("Location: cadastrar.php");
 }

 ?>

Comment: me desculpe n sei por o código aqui pra ficar visível

Comment: assim agora que eu entendi sua pergunta estar assim minha conexao.php <?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$banco = "novo";
$senha = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect ($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
if (!$conn ) {
    die('Não foi possível conectar: ' . mysql_error()); 
}
//echo 'Conexão bem sucedida';
?>

Comment: @michael clique em **[edit]** para adicionar seu código na pergunta.

Comment: Tente também `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tabela_nova; CREATE TABLE tabela_nova AS SELECT * FROM tabela_antiga;`

Comment: vou tentar muito obg bom mesma coisa , executa não faz nada e n da nem um erro.

Comment: Caso queira manter o código com `INSERT`, basta remover o trecho `(cl_coluna, created)` do seu código.

Comment: $result = "INSERT INTO tb_tabela2 SELECT  FROM tb_tabela"; tentei assim e $result = "INSERT INTO tb_tabela2  SELECT cl_coluna ,created FROM tb_tabela"; e nada o duro que estar certo mais n vai obs as duas tabelas então cravando tudo ok , elas são assim - id,cl_coluna, created as duas são iguais so o nome que nao tb_tabela e tb_tabela2

Comment: O correto é `INSERT INTO tb_tabela2 SELECT cl_coluna ,created FROM tb_tabela`. Verifique o retorno do `mysqli_query`

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo por favor sei que e simples mais aqui n ta indo faz duas semana que eu estou mexendo com php já ate fim um sistema de controle de condomínio agora quero fazer um relatório e quando esse relatório for executado ai entra essa parte ele copia da tabela a pra b e apaga a tabela a e so isso mais essa parte n ta indo banco de dados tudo ok conexão ok mais n vai pelo script php.